# Multivariable calculus.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have just started multivariable calculus and we have been given a definition.

$\text{We say that } l \in \mathbb{R} \text{ is a limit of a function } f \text{ at a point } P_0 \text{ if for every } \varepsilon >0 \text { there exists } \delta >0 \text{ such that for any } P \in U_\delta(P_0) \text{ one has } |f(P) - l| < \epsilon$

$$U_\delta(P_0) = \{P:|P - P_0| < \varepsilon\}$$

and a few examples to try:

Find the limit of the following functions as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$;

$$f = \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2},\ f = \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2},\ f = \frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2} $$

To me, they are all undefined at the origin.

Comment: They do not need to be defined at a point in order to have a limit at that point. Check the definition again

Comment: I see. If I was to substitute polar coordinates into $f$ to obtain $cos(\theta)sin(\theta)$, would that be a step in the right direction? I then no longer have a zero denominator?.

Comment: That would be a step in the right direction. Now if a limit should exist, then it must be unique; keep in mind that $\theta$ is arbitrary and you are finding the limit as $r \to 0$.

Comment: $r$ doesn't appear in polar version of $f$ though?

Comment: Does this mean the limit does not exist? if so why is that true?

Comment: The limit doesn't exist not because $r$ isn't present in the expression, but because $\theta$ can take any value. For the limit to exist, it should be independent of the choice of $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, time and patience :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: The limit is defined in term of $0 < |P-P_0| < \delta$, a 'punctured' neighbourhood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_1,f_2,f_3$ denote the three functions.

It is useful to note that $|xy| \le x^2+y^2$, hence $|f_1(x,y)| \le 1$. Also
note that $f_1(tx,ty) = f_1(x,y)$, hence $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} f_1(tx,ty) = f_1(x,y)$. Since $f_1(x,y)$ varies on the circle $x^2+y^2 = 1$, we see that this
shows that the limit does not exist as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

Note that $f_2(x,y) = x f_1(x,y)$, so $|f_2(x,y)| \le |x|$. It follows from this that the limit exists and is zero.

Finally, note that $f_3(x,y) = f_1(x^2,y)$.